# How to retrieve a unique data output using sql query (DISTINCT)?

Tags: mysql, sql

The data set is like this:

Table A

==type===|| ===score====

Two columns `type` ands `score`,

and Table B

==== id ==== || ==== data ====

Two columns as well `id` and `data`.

So, the details are as follows:

the `id` in table B should be an INNER JOIN for the `type` in table A.

Now an example case of data in each table,

## table A:

```
type == A, score = 75.
type == A, score = 80.   
type == B, score = 65. 
type == B, score = 75.
```

## and table B:

```
id == A, data = "Good score"
id == B, data = "Not bad..."
```

I want the query to only select the data that is unique and distinct to it's own category type i.e. if A it should be score of 80 and not score of 75 as 75 is unique to type B's score.

Hope that helps with the problem dilemma, and I would appreciate any guidance to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated subquery to check for the non existence of rows with the same score but different type.

```
SELECT a1.type,
       a1.score,
       b1.data
       FROM a a1
            INNER JOIN b b1
                       ON b1.id = a1.type
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM a a2
                                WHERE a2.score = a1.score
                                      AND a2.type <> a1.type);
```

Comment: Excellent @sticky bit, I had got through till the WHERE NOT EXISTS never thought of using that, thank you once again!

Comment: @FishingCode You can accept the answer by clicking on "Tick" sign in left of answer, if it has solved your purpose.